# Polynomial is zero for induced mapping of rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ a finitely-generated free $R$-module. Let $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ be an $R$-linear map, and $P_\phi(X)$ the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$. Let $f:R\rightarrow R'$ be a map of rings, and let $\phi':M\otimes_RR'\rightarrow M\otimes_RR'$ be the map induced by $\phi$.

(a) Suppose $P_\phi(\phi)=0$. Show that $P_{\phi'}(\phi')=0$.

(b) Suppose $f$ is injective and $P_{\phi'}(\phi')=0$. Show that $P_\phi(\phi)=0$.

I don't know how to relate $\phi$ and $\phi'$ in here, or what to do about $P_{\phi'}(\phi')$.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative? What is $R'$? Is there is a ring homomorphism $f : R \to R'$?

Comment: @user115654 Yes, you can assume $R$ is commutative. I've edited to answer your remaining questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $P_\phi(\phi)=0$ is always true (Cayley-Hamilton). But this exercise seems to be a preparation for the proof of this, reducing it to the case of fields.

After choosing a basis of $M$, we can imagine $\phi$ as an $n \times n$-matrix $M$ over $R$, and $P_\phi$ is the usual characteristic polynomial of this matrix, which is a certain polynomial computed from the entries of $M$. Then $\phi'$ corresponds to the matrix $M'$ over $R'$ whose entries are those of $M$ after applying $f$. Now you can easily see that $f(P_\phi(\phi))=P_{\phi'}(\phi')$ and everything follows.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. You are right that this exercise is a preparation for Cayley-Hamilton. I agree that we can imagine $\phi$ as an $n\times n$ matrix and compute $P_\phi$. But I don't understand why $\phi'$ corresponds to the matrix $M'$ over $R'$ with those entries, and $f(P_\phi(\phi))=P_{\phi'}(\phi')$. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please try it for a while.

Comment: Ok I've tried it and have a question. $P_\phi(\phi)$ is a polynomial in $\phi$ with coefficients in $R$, so what do you mean by $f(P_\phi(\phi))$? ($f$ is a map with domain $R$)

Comment: Well, $f$ induces a map on matrices.